# Split django models.py into multiple files inside folder (Django 3.0.4)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to split the *models.py* into multiple files inside a folder.

what is the proper way to do that ?

all the methods in the internet from 8 years ago and it's not working now.

## UPDATE 1:

```
test1
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    tests.py
    views.py
    migrations
    models
        __init__.py
        comment.py
        like.py
        post.py
        profile.py
```

inside ***init**.py*

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

from .like import Like
from .post import Post
from .profile import Profile
from .comment import Comment
```

inside *comment.py*

```
class Comment(models.Model): 
    commented_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    for_post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

inside *like.py*

```
class Like(models.Model): 
    liked_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

inside *post.py*

```
class Post(models.Model): 
    posted_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

inside *profile.py*

```
class Profile(models.Model): 
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

when I try to makemigrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations test1
```

I got this error:

```
(sandbox-qFsmxchL) λ python manage.py makemigrations test1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\USER\.virtualenvs\sandbox-qFsmxchL\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\USER\.virtualenvs\sandbox-qFsmxchL\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\USER\.virtualenvs\sandbox-qFsmxchL\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\USER\.virtualenvs\sandbox-qFsmxchL\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\USER\.virtualenvs\sandbox-qFsmxchL\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "c:\users\USER\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\sandbox\test1\models\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .like import Like
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\sandbox\test1\models\like.py", line 2, in <module>
    class Like(models.Model):
NameError: name 'models' is not defined
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do that putting them into a models folder, like:

```sh
models/
   - __init__.py
   - model_1.py
   - model_2.py
```

and `__init__.py` should import all models contained in the other files

```py
from .model_1 import Model1
from .model_2 import Model2
```

It is up to you to split them, depending on if you have a lot of models and if those are stricly related to each others.

Edit:

inside ***init**.py*

```py
from .post import Post
from .like import Like
from .profile import Profile
from .comment import Comment
```

inside *comment.py*

```py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

from test1.models import Post


class Comment(models.Model):
    commented_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    for_post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

inside *like.py*

```py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

from test1.models import Post


class Like(models.Model): 
    liked_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

inside *post.py*

```py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class Post(models.Model): 
    posted_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

inside *profile.py*

```py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class Profile(models.Model): 
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: You are not importing `from django.db import models` in the file containing `Like`. It must be imported in each file where you use `models.Model` class.